# fetch object within object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to fetch NAME which is in SKILLS.

[image]

For that I use filter for initial level sorting.Means I am able to sort rows but how do I fetch name?

```
   let r = this.topics.filter(a => {
          console.log('a is : ', a)
          return a.Skills.name
          
        })
```

Comment: `filter` is expected to filter.. maybe you meant `map`

Comment: @DiegoD also doesn't sort

Comment: @VLAZ good point, my brain discarded that part while reading the question.. so `filter` is totally out of place. You should first `sort` the list and then use `map` over it but surely not `filter`

Comment: @DiegoD by using map how will I be able to sort name?

Comment: what is `this.topics`?

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm not sure what should be happening. The code uses `.filter()` on `this.topics` yet the screenshot shows there is something called `rows`. The question also talks about sorting but not sure if it's relevant. Not really sure what's supposed to happen here. I'm mostly confident it's a duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865) but maybe there are more things needed (which are almost assuredly duplicates, as well).

Comment: Do you want to extract skills from the array or sort the array by name?

Comment: @Balaji extract name from skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what `Array.filter` does, it filters out/removes items from the array that does not match the criteria the user passes it, more about it here [filter docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

In this case you use a `Array.map` to transform the data, more about it here[map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
 let r = this.topics.map(item => {
      return item.skills.map( skill => skill.name)
 })
```

The above code will return something like `[['Writing', 'Reading'], ['Testing', 'Debugging']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map and Sort functions to achieve this.

```js
const topics = [{
  Skills: [{
    name: "Java",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "C++",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Python",
    id: 3
  }
]
}]

let r = topics.map((a) => {
  return a.Skills.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });
});

console.log(r);
```